# Is it possible to merge documentation topics?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-topics

If i see a couple topics (within a single tag) that should really be together, is there any way to merge their examples into one?

Say, [Reading files into pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pandas/1988/reading-files-into-pandas-dataframe#t=201607221212070461845) into [Read csv file into pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pandas/880/read-csv-file-into-pandas#t=201607221212136092196).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, there is a "move examples" option, where you can choose some or all examples to be moved to another topic.

[image]

If you choose to move all examples, the now-empty topic will be deleted.