# Migrating examples to another topic

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

In `gulp` tag, there's a topic for [Gulp Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/gulp/3310/gulp-tasks). Every other example of a task has been put there. I think the better way would be to create separate topic for separate task performed by Gulp. I had already submitted a minify file task in the `Gulp Task` topic.

So I went on and created a new topic called [Minify/Uglify Task](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/gulp/drafts/46680) and created examples to minify JS and CSS files. But since the example is directly taken from my earlier submitted example, I am assuming this is not the correct way to move a task.

Apart from that how can I move a certain example written by another user to a new arranged topic? I can't take credit of their writing and it'll be plagiarism anyways. So is there any way to migrate examples or is there any specific privilege required to do that (Since I can't find the option)?

Comment: There is a "move example" option: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328952/559745

Comment: @Floern Thanks for pointing it, I don't know how I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Florem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/559745/floern), I got the option to move example. I still didn't understand the documentation UI, so missed it.
To see the move example option, you need to first click on editing any example and create a draft (No need to save it).
Then you can see the `move example` option. You can submit this new change to any of your draft topic too, but the topic must not be in review. If it is, you'll need to `retract the edit` to the target topic, move the example and submit draft to both source and target topic.

You can select multiple examples to move, so the source topic will lose some examples while the target one will gain the same amount of examples.