# Duplicate topics in Python documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

In [Python documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topics), we have two topics on list comprehension:

- [List comprehensions (8 examples)](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/196/list-comprehensions)
- [List Comprehensions (5 examples)](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/5265/list-comprehensions)

Both have received hundreds of upvotes. How should we handle this?

By the way, this issue should have been solved when the topics are created, before it becomes messy. This somewhat reflects the fact that Stack Overflow Documentation needs a better regulation as soon as possible, if we're not going to admit it's [a failure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348030/5399734).

Comment: You can move examples from one topic to another: [Is it possible to merge documentation topics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328950/215552).

Comment: Wow, the names differ only by the case of a single letter. It does seem like the system should have caught that. We prohibit identical titles for questions, for crying out loud; we should *obviously* prevent identical titles for *documentation*. Unfortunately, to clean up the mess now is going to require manual intervention. You don't want to just merge them together, because you'll get a lot of duplication.